# How to solve Cross-Origin Request Blocked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I access my application, in console exist error like this :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://my.system.com/my-system/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Though I open on localhost

How to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share sample code?

Comment: What type of web server are you using?  Is this for a .NET application or something else?  CORS needs to be enabled and to do so is different depending on your web server and can be enabled by downloading a nuget package in .NET.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin that's not an effective way to resolve cross domain problems

Comment: @charlietfl The question relates to local development and no information on what http server is generating the CORS headers is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Add response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` on the server which host  `http://my.system.com/my-system/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0.` will solve cross domain request issue.